# PostgreSQL conditional select throwing error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database hosted on Heroku which is throwing me this error that I can't wrap my head around.

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, age SMALLINT, right_handed BOOLEAN)
SELECT 1 id FROM people WHERE age IN (1) AND right_handed IN (1)
```

It gives me the error:

`Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "IN"`

Don't know how to proceed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `autoincrement` in Postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name have I then misinterpreted point 18 on this docs file? https://cs50.readthedocs.io/heroku/ Do you maybe know what they mean by that?

Comment: What they mean is they did not proof read their docs. As has been said there is no `autoicrement` keyword in Postgres. The SO link they include is for `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` is not a valid option for `CREATE TABLE` in Postgres

You can use `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL`:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN myColumn BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Clear! What would be the alternative? Or would PRIMARY KEY suffice to also auto increment?

Comment: Apologies, you can use `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` :)

Comment: The use of serial is discouraged. Better use `identity` columns

Comment: No, a `PRIMARY KEY` is just the column or columns that constitute the primary key for a table. `AUTOINCREMENT` is a process for making the value of column increment automatically. The two are exclusive of each other, though `AUTOINCREMENT` is often used to supply values for a PK. It is also possible to autoincrement a column that is not a PK.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver OK, maybe I've missed your point but the question is about usage of `AUTOINCREMENT` in Postgres

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged  `User` as my comment was in response to his, in particular: 'Or would PRIMARY KEY suffice to also auto increment?'